# Using multiple Tech apps in CF

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I want to deploy application which is polyglot app ,
for example application that contain node / ruby / c# , how it can be done
since in the app root I use manifest.yml which can contain only one buildpack, so how the process should be?

Comment: Probably not what you mean, but if the overall "site" is served by apps of different runtimes, you can deploy the individual apps to different paths of the same hostname/domain. See here http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html

Comment: Do you want to run node / ruby / c# in a single container or can each of these run on their own in separate containers? "App" is used for both but with CF I think it would usually be the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a multi buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/multi-buildpack

I believe work is in progress to support this natively in CF, but that's not available yet (at least, the current cf CLI 6.23.0 has no provisions for it).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that with the multi-build pack you'll get staging for all of the build packs you want to use, but *only* the last build pack's command will be executed.  If a user needs to actually run multiple server processes in the same container, multi-build pack won't help.  Running multiple processes in the container is more complicated and it would be better to decompose the "app" into multiple smaller apps like @data_henrik suggested above.